# Error in python selenium webdriver chrome

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I have the following errors when using the selenium webdriver.chrome in Windows.  I am using Windows 10 Home 64 bit  and python verison Python 3.8.3 64-bit.  I have tried all solutions I could search but cannot solve it.

The following is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\clive\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 68, in __init__
    self.service = Service(
  File "C:\Users\clive\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\service.py", line 41, in __init__
    service.Service.__init__(self, executable_path, port=port, env=env,
  File "C:\Users\clive\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 42, in __init__
    self.port = utils.free_port()
  File "C:\Users\clive\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\utils.py", line 37, in free_port
    free_socket.listen(5)
OSError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```

This is the code

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'C:\\Users\\clive\\code\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe')
```

Error message came out after the second line of the code is run.

I appreciate your help on this.

Comment: as for me problem is your system, not code. Selenium needs socket (network connection) to access web browser but It seems system doesn't give you access to sockets.

Comment: pip install webdriver-manager , then import from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager and use it driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens due to firewall. Can you turn off the firewall and then check again.

Comment: Thanks. I turned off the firewall and that line of code is working.  Appreciate the help and answers to my question.

Comment: Hi @Chansun I am glad that my answer helped your problem. Can you mark my answer as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download python 3.7 to a separate location.
2. Download pycharm community edition.
3. Open pycharm and set a new virtual environment with python 3.7
4. Install selenium into that vertual environment.
5. Run the code.